# The Pancha Mahabhuta And Gross Universe

Tags: advaita, sankhya, panchabhoota

We say that the entire universe is made up of five elements.

**My question is** that apart from the five gross elements of (fire, water etc.) if we take any other thing eg. Phosphorus, ethanol etc. what is their composition with respect to the five subtle elements?

Comment: duplicate question. the modern meaning of 'elements' pertaining to gross matter is not the same use of the word when it is referred to in regard to the subtle elements. Scripture outlines the relationship between the subtle elements and the gross elements. It is through different combinations of the subtle elements that lend themselves to the gross elements. The use of the word element when used in reference to subtle elements is different then the use of the word elements in the gross world, especially the modern scientific usage